# spark replacing empty string with 0

Tags: apache-spark

Given this mocked up sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="foo"
    Name="foo"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="foo">
    <stuff>
        <list>
            <Details key="abdce" 
                Code=""/>
            <Details key="12346" 
                Code="10"/>
        </list>
    </stuff>
</Report>
```

When I read this file into a data frame in spark, spark is picking Long for the data type for the Code column (which is fine). However, when the Code value is an empty string ("") in the XML, it is being replaced with a 0.

```
val df= spark.read.format("xml").option("RootTag","Report").option("rowTag","Report").option("nullValue", "").load(source_file) 
df.withColumn("row", explode($"stuff.list.Details")).select($"row._Code",$"row._key").show
```

That returns:

```
+-----+----------+
|_Code|      _key|
+-----+----------+
|    0|     abdce|
|   10|     12346|
+-----+----------+
```

How do I prevent replacing the empty string with a 0?  It should be null on the first row.

Comment: Your code returns exactly what it is intended, I get a null instead of a zero (unlike you - but just what you want). I am using Spark 3.1.2 though.

Also, where does this key A162000236 come from? It is not listed in your XML, can the problem be somewhere else or the description be vague?

Comment: @sofizh-   Oh, sorry, the A162000236  is just me copy/pasting the wrong then, should be abcde, I'll correct that.  I'm on 3.12 (on Azure Synapse, if it's relevant?), but you are getting the correct result?

Comment: Yes, I get:

+-----+-----+

|_Code| _key|
+-----+-----+

| null|abdce|
|   10|12346|

+-----+-----+

which I assume is the correct result